# Image with rendering mode as alwaysTemplate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to change tint color of my image. I wonder why following code not working:

```
self.itemImage = [UIImageView new];
self.itemImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[_backgroundForCell addSubview:self.itemImage];
```

...

```
_itemImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:vm.imgName];
```

...

```
self.imageView.image = [self.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[self.imageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

I still see this:

[image]

Comment: Is that template image PNG image with contrast black?

Comment: @pedrouan yes. You right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may forgot to rename your variables:

replace

```
self.imageView.image = [self.imageView.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        [self.imageView setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

with

```
self.itemImage.image = [self.itemImage.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        [self.itemImage setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: You're welcome. It can happen to anybody, in night hours.